# Android screen size compatibility

Tags: android, screen, compatibility

I have a two questions.

First: I am looking at the Android compatibility definition document (CDD 4.0) and it states:

- Devices MUST have screen sizes of at least 2.5 inches in physical diagonal size
- Devices must report one of these densities: 120dpi, 160, 213, 240, 320
- The aspect ratio must be between 1.3333 and 1.85
- Must have minimum screen size of 460dp x 320dp (dp = density-independent pixel)

Suppose I have screen of 2"x3", with density of 120dpi, the screen would have:
    Diagonal: 3.61" = good
    Screen size: 320x480 dp = good
    This is nicely compatible with Android CDD

If I change the width from 2" to 1.7", I get
    Diagonal: 3.45" - still good
    Screen size: 272x480dp - NOT COMPATIBLE

My first question is, why specify a diagonal value, when the WIDTH is really what affects compatibility? The width must be 2" minimum.

Second: If I don't need to be Android compatible and stick with the 1.7" screen size, will applications that were built for the smallest compatible display be able to run on my device? Will the UI of this application be cropped when run in my device?

Thanks much for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just an easy way to specify the requirement. If you have a portrait device, the width is smaller than the height. If you have a landscape device, the width is the large dimension. It's just easier to say "the diagonal" than "the smaller of the two screen dimensions when the device is laid flat" or something like that. There are lots of ways to say essentially the same thing.

If your device is smaller than the CDD requires, you will probably want to still report in Android that your device is of screen size small, so I imagine apps will run but layouts for many of them will likely not fit well as people will tend to test on CDD-conformant devices. It very much depends on what layouts people used, but I wouldn't be surprised if you saw some cropping.